# How to send an image to a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a simplified web server, I was able to handle sending the HTML pages properly

but when I get a request for an image, my code doesn't give the browser the image

```
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tempSplitArray[1],FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
//The tempSplitArray //recieves the request from the browser
byte[] ar = new byte[(long)fstream.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
{
    ar[i] = (byte)fstream.ReadByte();
}
string byteLine = "Content-Type: image/JPEG\n" + BitConverter.ToString(ar);
sw.WriteLine(byteLine);//This is the network stream writer
sw.Flush();
fstream.Close();
```

Excuse my ignorance and if there are any questions, or my question is not clear enough, let me know.

Comment: Are u using web forms and is this your handler code??

Comment: Nope, I am building a console application and I am sending my requests from the browser by typing http://127.0.0.1/index.html<br>
That page has an image tag, so the browser sends a request to ask for the image, the code above is supposed to handle that request, but it's not :(

Comment: [C# read image object in to web request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939790/c-read-image-object-in-to-web-request)

[c# how to write a jpg image from request.binaryread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715737/c-how-to-write-a-jpg-image-from-request-binaryread)

please do google stackoverflow :)

Comment: Why are you converting the bytes to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want your response to look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: *length of image*

Binary Image Data goes here
```

I'm assuming `sw` is a `StreamWriter`, but you need to write the *raw* bytes of the image.

So how about:

```
byte[] ar;
using(FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tempSplitArray[1],FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);)
{
    //The tempSplitArray //recieves the request from the browser
    ar = new byte[(long)fstream.Length];

    fstream.read(ar, 0, fstream.Length);
}

sw.WriteLine("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
sw.WriteLine("Content-Length: {0}", ar.Length); //Let's 
sw.WriteLine(); 
sw.BaseStream.Write(ar, 0, ar.Length);
```

It really helps to use a tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to view the communications between browsers and a (real) webserver and try to replicate that.